# CSS@ Drawing diagonal lines mantaining Tilt angle and legth of line fixed

Tags: css, rotation, line, angle, vector-graphics

I want to be able to draw lines that dont go either Up Down or Left-Right. They are rotate a certain angle.
I would like to be able to write the code with the certain angle and select the size correctly.
The problem is that the way I've learnt to do it is by adding a small box with really tiny Width or Height and then Rorating it with transform.
The problem on tweaking this it disadjust the length and the position and I get quite confused, not being able to draw properly.

Say I use a Canvas, to simply it squared:

```
.box{
    position: relative;
    height: 640px;
    width: 640px;
    background: white;
  }
```

And I draw a horizontal line in the middle.

```
.shape1{
     position: absolute;
     top: 50%;
     background-color:black;
     width: 100%;
     height: 1%;
}
```

(obviously shape1 is nested within the box)

Then I apply

```
transform: rorate(45deg);
```

And the disadjustment starts. Obviously the diagonal is not gonna complete the whole square, but what adjustments can I do in order to mantain the angle on 45deg, start in (100,0) and ends in (0,100) 
(supossing that maxX=100 and maxY=100)

I have found translateX and translateY useful functions, but I still need some kind of function to adjust the length of the line.

Has anyone has any idea on how to do this?

Thanks very much

Comment: You need javascript for that

Comment: can you share a screenshot of the result you want?

Answer (score 0):

You might use `linear-gradient`:

```css
section {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 1em;
  outline: solid 1px red;
  background: linear-gradient(to top right, #0000 calc(50% - 1px), #000, #0000 calc(50% + 1px))
}

.square {width:100px; height:100px;}

.rect {width:187px; height:103px;}
```

```html
<section class="square"></section>
<section class="rect"></section>
```